# copyValueOf in Java?

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CourseSplitter {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] course; //course code format: ABCDE##
    String code;
    //int num; 
    System.out.println("Input Course: ");
    course = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println(course);
    code = String.copyValueOf(course, 0, 4);
    System.out.println(code);       
   }    
}
```

I don't know how I should let the user input the course when I'm using a character array instead of string. In short, how do I use the "scanner" on character arrays?

The instruction is the user will input a course code in the format: ABCDE##
Then, the program must split it into the course name and the course number. So, I had to use the copyValueOf method but it doesn't seem to work because from all the articles I read online, they used a char[] array but initialized the array with some value. So I was wondering how I could use the scanner on character arrays.

Comment: Why do you need a character array?

Comment: All of the articles I read online had the char[] so I thought it was a required or something...

Comment: Not at all, you can do whatever you want with your program. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just read a string from the scanner and then call `String.toCharArray`? It's not even clear why you *need* a char array here...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just read a string directly with `scanner.nextLine`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CourseSplitter {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input Course: ");
    String course = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println(course);
    String code = course.substring(0, 5); //You put 4 but it left out the last letter in the course name. I changed it to 5 and it worked but I'm confused since the index always start with 0.
    System.out.println(code);    
    String num = course.substring(5, 6);
    System.out.println(num);   
   }    
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear with my question but I updated it with more details below it.

Comment: @nutellafella: See my edit. You can just the first 4 characters of the string `course` and put them in the string `code`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! My only problem now is the number. When I input ABCDE12, the only number that appears in the output is '2'. This is what I used: String num = course.substring(5, 6);

Comment: @nutellafella: No problem. I added your edit to my answer. Don't forget to mark the most useful answer as accepted for future readers to find it quickly.